Does someone know the name the manga about a man who rescued a boy? His consciousness is transferred into the boy's body
The manga is about a man (who was a boss, I think) who wanted to learn a lot. He saw a boy falling from a balcony and saved him, but the man died in the process. The man's consciousness transferred into the boy's body, and he continued living as the boy, attending his high school to learn.
The man in the boy's body often says things like "this generation" and "kid" because he was actually an older man (I'm not sure of his exact age, but he was definitely not a teenager—probably 40 and up.) Meanwhile, the man's body died with the soul of the boy inside it. It's as if their minds swapped bodies, I think.
I also believe that the boy was bullied by his classmates before he died in the man's body. (I think this was a bl-boys love.)

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?
